# SQL Server 2008 R2 Create index

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Now I am looking for your help to create index on these.

Now this is my table structure

[image: table description screen cap]

This the query I need index for maximum performance.

```
select PageId 
    from tblPages 
    where UrlChecksumCode = @UrlChecksumCode 
        and PageUrl = @PageUrl
```

Now I am very bad with indexes. I plan like that when the query is executing it will find first that `UrlChecksumCode` rows then look pageurl columns. If you also explain me why to make such index I really appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: One is 1000 nvarchar another is bigint. I suppose there should be big difference on indexes.

Comment: There can't be multiple records with same url.

Comment: Andrew Barber i suppose you really did not understand the question.

Comment: Update : I moved to new system (32 bit hashing including page id and page url). SQL server cpu usage decreased to 1% from almost 100% :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

one way, since your pageURL is long(nvarchar(1000) and an index can only be 900 bytes if you don't use included columns, I have created this [index with included columns](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-advent-2011-day-20)

```
create index ix_IndexName on tblPages (UrlChecksumCode) INCLUDE(PageUrl)
```

or

```
create index ix_IndexName on tblPages (UrlChecksumCode) INCLUDE(PageUrl, PageID)
```

See also [SQL Server covering indexes](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-covering-indexes)

why is URL nvarchar instead of varchar...can they be unicode? if not make it varchar and save 1/2 the size

Comment: This is not really i am looking for. The index should be on urlchecksumcode. Maybe not include pageurl to index ?

Comment: The order of the columns in the index will first look for urlchecksumcode, read the article I added to my question

Comment: The new url count will be so much. Wouldn't that bring extra stress ? I suppose including PageId is more logical. Also i am reading the article.

Comment: It seems like this is the query i need : Create nonclustered index indexPageUrlHash On tblPages (UrlChecksumCode,PageUrl,PageId) am i right ?

Comment: that is the same as the 2nd one in my answer, you need to use with included columns since you are exceeding 900 bytes

Comment: SQLMenace what is the include difference ?

Answer (score 2):

**Create Nonclustered Indexes**

```
       create nonclustered index indexname on tablename(columnname)
```

**Drop Index**

```
       Drop Index index name on tablename
```

**See all Indexes in a database**

```
       select * from sys.indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an index over `(UrlChecksumCode and PageUrl)`, because that's what it's selecting against.

Though you might, under some data patterns, have better performance if you just index over (`UrlChecksumCode`) because the `PageUrl` would require a larger text index

Comment: yes but i am looking how to make the index . I am already aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create cluster then , you can used this,

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_IndexName ON tblPages (UrlChecksumCode) INCLUDE(PageUrl)
```

The following query retrieves the indexes created on your table.

```
EXECUTE sp_helpindex tablename
```

**Brief introduction for cluster indexing:-**

A clustered index defines the order in which data is physically stored in a table. Table data can be sorted in only way, therefore, there can be only one clustered index per table. In SQL Server, the primary key constraint automatically creates a clustered index on that particular column. or you can create custom cluster index removing default cluster index which created by primary key.

Answer (score -3):

i think even we can use clusterd index as for fast search like
create clusteredindex someName 
on tableName(columnName1,columnName2,......)
but only one clustered index we can create for a tab